# Removing rows in a cell array without a specific word

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array

I have a cell array in MATLAB with majority of rows containing the word sentiment and these are the only ones relevant to my algorithm. However, some rows do not contain the word 'sentiment', so I wish to removed these. Could anyone provide a solution ?

Using...

```
IDX = strfind(datesent,'sentiment')
```

... I can identify which rows down contain the particular word but I am unsure as to how I should structure this as a command.

Or could I create a new array with just these rows ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/), and `=[]` for deletion. Guessing from [the strfind documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) (cannot try at the moment), probably like this:

```
 isabsent = cellfun(@isempty,IDX);
 datesent(isabsent)=[];
```

Comment: this would remove all rows containing the word sentiment. I need it so the only rows left are those with the word sentiment

Comment: @Adam The answer works for me. Note `isempty` kinda "negates" `IDX`